# Spark Post and Android

Tags: java, android, sparkpost

I am trying to send email's using spark post, i'm facing these issues

1. HTML tags are not reflecting in emails
2. How to add attachments (images) in my mails.

Comment: How are you sending? what your message body (request) looks like, what is your content type and how they're appearing at recipient end?

Comment: Here's a link to the documentation for [inline images](https://developers.sparkpost.com/api/transmissions.html#header-inline-image-attributes). Seeing an example of what you're sending would help.